# I cannot create a string variable in Java

Tags: java, string

I am making a text adventure (I'm only a beginner and this is for practice). I need to make a string varible under name.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Adventure {

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        name str;
        System.out.println("YOU WAKE IN A COLD, DARK PRISON CELL. THERE IS A MAN.");
        Scanner NAME = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ah, you are awake. Who are you? (ENTER YOU NAME)");
    }

}
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can't give variable a name dynamically.

Comment: I don't know what `name str;` is. Perhaps you meant `String name;`?

Comment: Um, the ' name str; ' part doesnt work?

Comment: Not unless you have a class called "`name`"

Comment: @JonLin Which would of course be a problem in it's own right :)

Comment: I think you want some thing  `String name = NAME.nextLine();`

Comment: You should start with the basics by reading a book or just working through the Java tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: As a side note: it's unintuitive to give a scanner variable the name `NAME`. The common practice would be to call it `scannner` or `scan` or something like that. Besides the above mentioned Java Tutorial, it would also be useful for you to read ["Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 5):

You need to make:

```
 name str;
```

into :

```
String name;
```